# Unable to share videos to Youtube, which are present inside /mnt/sdcard/Android/data in sd card

Tags: android, video, youtube, android-sdcard

I'm facing this really weird issue of not being able to share any videos to youtube, which are present inside **/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.sec.example**. That is locally stored in my application. When I copy the videos to outside of this folder (**/mnt/sdcard/Android/...**), then I'm able to share via YouTube.

This issue occurs only for **Youtube**. Sharing via other applications viz., Gmail, DropBox, Facebook, Bluetooth, etc. works fine in all cases.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is the pic of code from [Share files](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/02/share-with-intents.html)

```
Intent intent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

// Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide what to do with it.
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, “Some Subject Line”);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, “Body of the message, woot!”);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, “How do you want to share?”));
```